# NoSuchMethodError in Spark 3.4 with JDK8u362 & JDK8u372

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-8

My project was on spark 3.3 with JDK8u362 and I tried updating it to spark 3.4, Official documentation of spark 3.4 says it works with JDK8u362 and above but when I tried upgrading docker base image of spark to JDK8u362 and JDK8u372 it is failing at runtime with below error, For JDK8u362 it throws error for Java.nio.CharBuffer.position method and for JDK8u372 it throws error for java.nio.ByteBuffer.flip method.
But when I run with JDK11 image in spark Docker file it works fine.
Am I missing anything or how to fix this issue as I want to run it with JDK8.

```
ava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.CharBuffer.position(I)Ljava/nio/CharBuffer;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.unescapeSQLString(ParserUtils.scala:220) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.string(ParserUtils.scala:95) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.$anonfun$createString$2(AstBuilder.scala:2632) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286) ~[scala-library-2.12.17.jar:?]
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943) ~[scala-library-2.12.17.jar:?]
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943) ~[scala-library-2.12.17.jar:?]
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431) ~[scala-library-2.12.17.jar:?]
        at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74) ~[scala-library-2.12.17.jar:?]
        at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73) ~[scala-library-2.12.17.jar:?]
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56) ~[scala-library-2.12.17.jar:?]
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286) ~[scala-library-2.12.17.jar:?]
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279) ~[scala-library-2.12.17.jar:?]
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108) ~[scala-library-2.12.17.jar:?]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.createString(AstBuilder.scala:2632) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.$anonfun$visitStringLiteral$1(AstBuilder.scala:2618) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.withOrigin(ParserUtils.scala:160) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitStringLiteral(AstBuilder.scala:2618) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitStringLiteral(AstBuilder.scala:58) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParser$StringLiteralContext.accept(SqlBaseParser.java:19511) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitChildren(AstBuilder.scala:73) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParserBaseVisitor.visitConstantDefault(SqlBaseParserBaseVisitor.java:1735) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParser$ConstantDefaultContext.accept(SqlBaseParser.java:18373) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitChildren(AstBuilder.scala:73) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParserBaseVisitor.visitValueExpressionDefault(SqlBaseParserBaseVisitor.java:1567) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParser$ValueExpressionDefaultContext.accept(SqlBaseParser.java:17491) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.typedVisit(AstBuilder.scala:63) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.expression(AstBuilder.scala:1630) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.$anonfun$withPredicate$1(AstBuilder.scala:1870) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.withOrigin(ParserUtils.scala:160) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.withPredicate(AstBuilder.scala:1784) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.$anonfun$visitPredicated$1(AstBuilder.scala:1768) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.withOrigin(ParserUtils.scala:160) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitPredicated(AstBuilder.scala:1765) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitPredicated(AstBuilder.scala:58) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParser$PredicatedContext.accept(SqlBaseParser.java:16909) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitChildren(AstBuilder.scala:73) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParserBaseVisitor.visitExpression(SqlBaseParserBaseVisitor.java:1518) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParser$ExpressionContext.accept(SqlBaseParser.java:16766) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.typedVisit(AstBuilder.scala:63) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.expression(AstBuilder.scala:1630) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.$anonfun$visitParenthesizedExpression$1(AstBuilder.scala:2361) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.withOrigin(ParserUtils.scala:160) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitParenthesizedExpression(AstBuilder.scala:2361) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitParenthesizedExpression(AstBuilder.scala:58) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParser$ParenthesizedExpressionContext.accept(SqlBaseParser.java:18036) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitChildren(AstBuilder.scala:73) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParserBaseVisitor.visitValueExpressionDefault(SqlBaseParserBaseVisitor.java:1567) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParser$ValueExpressionDefaultContext.accept(SqlBaseParser.java:17491) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.typedVisit(AstBuilder.scala:63) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.expression(AstBuilder.scala:1630) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.$anonfun$visitPredicated$1(AstBuilder.scala:1766) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.withOrigin(ParserUtils.scala:160) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitPredicated(AstBuilder.scala:1765) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitPredicated(AstBuilder.scala:58) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParser$PredicatedContext.accept(SqlBaseParser.java:16909) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.typedVisit(AstBuilder.scala:63) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.expression(AstBuilder.scala:1630) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.$anonfun$visitLogicalBinary$4(AstBuilder.scala:1694) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at scala.collection.SeqLike.$anonfun$reverseMap$2(SeqLike.scala:295) ~[scala-library-2.12.17.jar:?]
        at scala.collection.SeqLike.reverseMap(SeqLike.scala:294) ~[scala-library-2.12.17.jar:?]
        at scala.collection.SeqLike.reverseMap$(SeqLike.scala:289) ~[scala-library-2.12.17.jar:?]
        at scala.collection.AbstractSeq.reverseMap(Seq.scala:45) ~[scala-library-2.12.17.jar:?]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.$anonfun$visitLogicalBinary$1(AstBuilder.scala:1694) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.withOrigin(ParserUtils.scala:160) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitLogicalBinary(AstBuilder.scala:1669) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitLogicalBinary(AstBuilder.scala:58) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParser$LogicalBinaryContext.accept(SqlBaseParser.java:16958) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.typedVisit(AstBuilder.scala:63) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.expression(AstBuilder.scala:1630) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.withWhereClause(AstBuilder.scala:703) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.$anonfun$visitCommonSelectQueryClausePlan$2(AstBuilder.scala:807) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$EnhancedLogicalPlan$.optionalMap$extension(ParserUtils.scala:256) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitCommonSelectQueryClausePlan(AstBuilder.scala:807) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.$anonfun$withSelectQuerySpecification$1(AstBuilder.scala:788) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.withOrigin(ParserUtils.scala:160) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.withSelectQuerySpecification(AstBuilder.scala:776) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.$anonfun$visitRegularQuerySpecification$1(AstBuilder.scala:668) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.withOrigin(ParserUtils.scala:160) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitRegularQuerySpecification(AstBuilder.scala:656) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitRegularQuerySpecification(AstBuilder.scala:58) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParser$RegularQuerySpecificationContext.accept(SqlBaseParser.java:10386) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitChildren(AstBuilder.scala:73) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParserBaseVisitor.visitQueryPrimaryDefault(SqlBaseParserBaseVisitor.java:902) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParser$QueryPrimaryDefaultContext.accept(SqlBaseParser.java:9891) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitChildren(AstBuilder.scala:73) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParserBaseVisitor.visitQueryTermDefault(SqlBaseParserBaseVisitor.java:888) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParser$QueryTermDefaultContext.accept(SqlBaseParser.java:9658) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.typedVisit(AstBuilder.scala:63) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.plan(AstBuilder.scala:114) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.$anonfun$visitQuery$1(AstBuilder.scala:120) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.withOrigin(ParserUtils.scala:160) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitQuery(AstBuilder.scala:119) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitQuery(AstBuilder.scala:58) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParser$QueryContext.accept(SqlBaseParser.java:6891) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitChildren(AstBuilder.scala:73) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParserBaseVisitor.visitStatementDefault(SqlBaseParserBaseVisitor.java:69) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParser$StatementDefaultContext.accept(SqlBaseParser.java:1988) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visit(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:18) ~[antlr4-runtime-4.9.3.jar:4.9.3]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.$anonfun$visitSingleStatement$1(AstBuilder.scala:80) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.withOrigin(ParserUtils.scala:160) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitSingleStatement(AstBuilder.scala:80) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.$anonfun$parsePlan$2(ParseDriver.scala:92) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.withOrigin(ParserUtils.scala:160) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.$anonfun$parsePlan$1(ParseDriver.scala:92) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:127) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:52) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parsePlan(ParseDriver.scala:89) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$2(SparkSession.scala:633) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:632) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:827) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:630) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:671) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at com.cisco.intersight.cep.AdvisoryProcessorTask.processActions(AdvisoryProcessorTask.java:376) ~[orion.jar:?]
        at com.cisco.intersight.cep.AdvisoryProcessorTask.processAdvisory(AdvisoryProcessorTask.java:329) ~[orion.jar:?]
        at com.cisco.intersight.cep.AdvisoryProcessorTask.processAdvisories(AdvisoryProcessorTask.java:306) ~[orion.jar:?]
        at com.cisco.intersight.cep.AdvisoryProcessorTask.run(AdvisoryProcessorTask.java:286) ~[orion.jar:?]
        at com.cisco.intersight.cep.AdvisoryDriver.main(AdvisoryDriver.java:115) ~[orion.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_352]
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:1020) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:192) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:215) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:91) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1111) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1120) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]%
```

Error with JDK8u362

````
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task serialization failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.flip()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.flip()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
        at org.apache.spark.util.io.ChunkedByteBufferOutputStream.toChunkedByteBuffer(ChunkedByteBufferOutputStream.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$.blockifyObject(TorrentBroadcast.scala:362)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.writeBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.<init>(TorrentBroadcast.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcastInternal(SparkContext.scala:1548)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1530)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:1535)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1353)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleMapStageSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:1334)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2934)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2923)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2912)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)

        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2785) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2721) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2720) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62) ~[scala-library-2.12.17.jar:?]
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55) ~[scala-library-2.12.17.jar:?]
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49) ~[scala-library-2.12.17.jar:?]
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2720) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:1545) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1353) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleMapStageSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:1334) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2934) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2923) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2912) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.flip()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
        at org.apache.spark.util.io.ChunkedByteBufferOutputStream.toChunkedByteBuffer(ChunkedByteBufferOutputStream.scala:115) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$.blockifyObject(TorrentBroadcast.scala:362) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.writeBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:160) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.<init>(TorrentBroadcast.scala:99) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:38) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:78) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcastInternal(SparkContext.scala:1548) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1530) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:1535) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
        ... 6 more 
    ```
````

Comment: It looks very unstable to continue using JDK 8, while Spark grows in versions. I agree that Spark 3.4.0 is very unstable, I've experienced it myself. But it is more done to run with JDK 11 than JDK 8.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan do you mean a bug in spark 3.4.0 ? I have an issue where after upgrading to spark 3.4.0, It cannot find my application jar and says NosuchFileException ?

Answer (score 0):

This errors usually indicate that the code was built in a version of JDK newer than 8, with target JDK 8, but using the library of the newer version that contains new methods. Since those methods are not available in JDK 8 hence the error: NoSuchMethodError. This may be caused by Spark being inadvertently with JDK 11 as described. Running in JDK 11 seems advisable.

Comment: but on the official documentation of spark they say that spark 3.4 should work on JDK8u362 and above, [Spark Docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/)

Comment: Yes but the error may be indicating a bug.

Comment: you @aled do you mean a bug in spark 3.4.0 ? I have an issue where after upgrading to spark 3.4.0, It cannot find my application jar and says NosuchFileException

Comment: @aled I'm using JDK 17 the current one.